# Problem with NTLM authentication on executing http request by Spring WebClient and HttpComponentsClientHttpConnector

Tags: java, spring, ntlm, apache-httpclient-5.x

I try to execute HTTP requests using [Apache HttpClient 5](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.1.x/) and I need NTLM authentication, which is supported by this client out of the box. But when I try to use it with Spring WebClient by HttpComponentsClientHttpConnector, there is an issue.

[HttpComponentsClientHttpConnector](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/reactive/HttpComponentsClientHttpConnector.java) initializes [HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/reactive/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java) to execute request. But if the request has a body, [HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/reactive/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java) initializes ReactiveEntityProducer, which is not repeatable, so that, while I need [to execute 3 requests to authenticatу using NTLM](http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html), only one actually happens.

Is it possible to change this behavior?

**UPDATE**

Added my prototype java-code:

```java
BasicCredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(
    new AuthScope("https", "some-host", 443, null, StandardAuthScheme.NTLM),
    new NTCredentials("test-user", "test-password".toCharArray(), null, null)
);

WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .clientConnector(new HttpComponentsClientHttpConnector
        (HttpAsyncClients
            .custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
            .setTargetAuthenticationStrategy(DefaultAuthenticationStrategy.INSTANCE)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(
                RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setAuthenticationEnabled(true)
                    .setTargetPreferredAuthSchemes(Collections.singletonList(StandardAuthScheme.NTLM))
                    .setExpectContinueEnabled(true)
                    .build())
            .build()))
    .build();

webClient
    .method(HttpMethod.POST)
    .uri("https://some-host/execute")
    .header("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8")
    .header("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messagesCreateItem")
    .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
    .header("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7")
    .header("Expect", "100-continue")
    .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(
        "<SOME_XML_BODY>"
    ))
    .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> {
        return clientResponse.bodyToMono(Object.class);
    })
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: NTLM is authentication not authorization

Comment: Well, NTLM is crap. You need to leverage expect continue header to cope with non-repeatable requests.

Comment: @Michael-O how exactly expect continue header could help? I tried to add Expect: 100-Continue, but nothing is changed.

Comment: First of all, you need to do it [here](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.5/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.Builder.html#setExpectContinueEnabled(boolean)). The benefit of this is the client does *not* send the body, but the headers only and asks the server to evaluate them. So the server will tell you please authenticate first and keep the request body for you.

Comment: @Michael-O Still the same result. I added code snippet of my prototype to question.

Comment: NTLM requires the NetBIOS domain to be provided. If nothing works you need to provide full debug logs to us.

Comment: Do a cheap GET or HEAD first.

Comment: please check my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74575496/spring-webclient-windows-ntlm-authentication/77021558#77021558